# What are the best practices for creating a HTML 5 website that may or may not be migrated to a Wordpress

Tags: html, css, web, wordpress-theming

Gist:
I am entrusted with a task to create a website for an app. The website is more or less static and will have very little interaction with a Database. It is basically used for informative purposes and also to allow users to purchase virtual stuff for the iPad app. The website may or may not be migrated to Wordpress.

Question:
1.Given the above scenario what would be the best practices to follow moving forward, so as to keep the website flexible.

1. Am I right in saying that the migration can be easy, esp for the static pages, by creating a new Wordpress theme?
2. How much time should (just give me a approximate) the website take?

It is my first website and I really want it to be good, esp since the iPad app being developed is looking pretty awesome.
Thanks a ton.

Comment: There are a lot of issues you didn't mention which would significantly impact the development time. For example, is there a hosted / integrated ecommerce cart? Or, how do you plan on accommodating mobile devices, a separately built mobile version of the site, or a flexible layout that adjusts to device width?

Comment: The e-commerce cart:I intend to use a wordpress plugin.
Mobile:create a flexible layout
I also intend to create my own theme for Wordpress

Answer (score 1):

It is definitely not going to be a cut and paste job. Wordpress' intended use is serving dynamic content and is heavily "templated out".

You can easily create static pages but they may not jibe with your theme without a lot of elbow grease.

Basically you have to decide whether to jam your content into a theme, or create a theme around your content. I highly recommend starting with wordpress and a specific theme, and customizing from there. It's the path of least resistance.

How long this will take is too hard to call. Depends on the amount and complexity of content. Also on your skills and familiarity with HTML+CSS and wordpress. I would not underestimate this task.

Comment: I guess creating my own template would be good. I mean it would be customed for the website. USing wordpress may help with e-commerce plugins. I have mediocre expertise in html - css.

Answer (score 0):

Apples and oranges, I'm afraid. As with any CMS headers, navigation and footers are usually generated using a templating system. There is no such equivalent in a static site.